# how to get values from a json to implement it in a drop down list?

Tags: jquery

```
var g_Vehicle = {
        g_Vehicle1: [
            Year: "2011",
            Make: "abc",
            Model: "Avenger",
            SubModel: "def"
        ],
        g_Vehicle2: [
            Year: "2012",
            Make: "abc",
            Model: "200",
            SubModel: "deft"
        ],
        g_Vehicle3: [
            Year: "2011",
            Make: "dfg",
            Model: "300",
            SubModel: "sde"
        ],
}
```

Comment: How do you want the dropdown lists? 3 lists or single list?

Comment: @venumadhuri: That's not JSON, it's an attempt at a JavaScript object literal. But it's an invalid one, your `[` and `]` should be `{` and `}`.

Comment: can any one tell me why im losing my points? Im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it together with jQuery...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var g_Vehicle = {
  g_Vehicle1: {
      Year: "2011",
      Make: "abc",
      Model: "Avenger",
      SubModel: "def"
  },
  g_Vehicle2: {
      Year: "2012",
      Make: "abc",
      Model: "200",
      SubModel: "deft"
  },
  g_Vehicle3: {
      Year: "2011",
      Make: "dfg",
      Model: "300",
      SubModel: "sde"
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    (function() {
        var l = '';
        for(var id in g_Vehicle) {
            l += '<option value="'+id+'">'+id+'</option>'           
        }
        $('#mymenu')
        .html(l)
        .change(function() {

            //Test here
            var r = g_Vehicle[$(this).val()];           
            alert('Year: ' + r.Year+'\nMake: ' + r.Make+'\nModel: ' + r.Model+'\nSubModel: ' + r.SubModel+'\n');

        });     
    })();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" name="myform">
<select id="mymenu" name="mymenu"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object literal. An invalid one, your syntax is incorrect...

```
var g_Vehicle = {
        g_Vehicle1: [
        //  v------------------------here
            Year: "2011",
            Make: "abc",
            Model: "Avenger",
            SubModel: "def"
        ],
        ...
```

`[` ... `]` is how you define an array, but what you're putting inside them is how you define object properties. If you change your `[` and `]` above to `{` and `}`, it would be valid, but awkward to use. Instead, just make the whole thing an array of objects:

```
var g_Vehicles = [
        {
            Year: "2011",
            Make: "abc",
            Model: "Avenger",
            SubModel: "def"
        },
        {
            Year: "2012",
            Make: "abc",
            Model: "200",
            SubModel: "deft"
        },
        {
            Year: "2011",
            Make: "dfg",
            Model: "300",
            SubModel: "sde"
        }
];
```

Then you can loop through that, generating whatever kind of drop-down you want. For example, here's one way to create a `select` drop-down:

```
var markup = ['<select>'];
$.each(g_Vehicles, function(index, vehicle) {
    markup.push('<option value=' + index + '>' +
                vehicle.Make + '-' + vehicle.Model + '-' + vehicle.SubModel +
                '</option>');
});
markup.push('</select>');
$("selector_for_some_container").html(markup.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a JavaScript object literal not a JSON.

So use the jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function:

```
g_Vehicle.each(function(index) {
    $('select').append($('<option>' + g_Vehicle[index].Make + '</option>'));
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated the answer. Didn't check. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will get you started. Expand on this depending on which drop down you are filling in.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var g_Vehicle = [
    {
        Year: "2011",
        Make: "Ram",
        Model: "Avenger",
        SubModel: "Dart",
        Vin: "1C1"
    },
    {
        Year: "2012",
        Make: "Dodge",
        Model: "200",
        SubModel: "Dart",
        Vin: "1C2"
    },
    {
        Year: "2011",
        Make: "Chrysler",
        Model: "300",
        SubModel: "Durango",
        Vin: "1C3"
    }
];

var year="2011";

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i in g_Vehicle){
       if(g_Vehicle[i].Year == year){
           $('#make').append($('<option>' + g_Vehicle[i].Make + '</option>'));
       }
    }
});


</script>
<body>
<select id="make"></select>
</body>
</html>
```